# Rsync error (104) Using Localhost IP

Tags: networking, rsync

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 running UFW.

**Problem**:
No matter, whether I use rsync or rsyncd to backup my home folder, with the command below.  I always get `rsync error (104)`:

```
cputool --load-limit 7.5 -- nice -n -5 rsync -avxP --delete --timeout=180 --rsync-path="rsync" --log-file=/var/log/rsync.log --exclude 'snap'  --exclude 'lost+found' --exclude=".*" --exclude=".*/" 127.0.0.1::home /path/to/external/backup/folder
```

nmap confirrms that the rsync port is open:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
873/tcp open  rsync
```

When I check my rsync log, I see:

```
2022/08/09 08:43:44 [2610980] rsync error: received SIGUSR1 (code 19) at main.c(145
8) [receiver=3.1.3]
2022/08/09 08:44:00 [2622644] name lookup failed for 192.168.0.11: Name or service
not known
2022/08/09 08:44:00 [2622644] connect from UNKNOWN (192.168.0.11)
2022/08/09 08:44:05 [2622644] rsync on home/ from UNKNOWN (192.168.0.11)
```

I thought the problem might be with dnsmasq, which I run for local web development, so I added  `listen-address=127.0.0.1,192.168.0.11`  in my `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

no luck, same error.

Note: when I `grep -R "192.168.0.11" /etc` , I get:

```
/etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save:-A ufw-user-forward -p tcp -m tcp -s 192.168.0.11/32 -d 192.168.0.47/32 -i wg-client8 -o wlp0s10f2 --dport 22 --sport 22 -j ufw-user-logging-forward
/etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save:-A ufw-user-forward -p tcp -m tcp -s 192.168.0.11/32 -d 192.168.0.47/32 -i wg-client8 -o wlp0s10f2 --dport 22 --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
/etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save:-A ufw-user-forward -p udp -m udp -s 192.168.0.11/32 -d 192.168.0.47/32 -i wg-client8 -o wlp0s10f2 --dport 22 --sport 22 -j ufw-user-logging-forward
/etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save:-A ufw-user-forward -p udp -m udp -s 192.168.0.11/32 -d 192.168.0.47/32 -i wg-client8 -o wlp0s10f2 --dport 22 --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
/etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save:-A ufw-user-logging-forward -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -m limit -s 192.168.0.11/32 -d 192.168.0.47/32 -i wg-client8 -o wlp0s10f2 --dport 22 --sport 22 --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 --ctstate NEW -j LOG  --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
/etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save:-A ufw-user-logging-forward -p tcp -m tcp -s 192.168.0.11/32 -d 192.168.0.47/32 -i wg-client8 -o wlp0s10f2 --dport 22 --sport 22 -j RETURN
/etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save:-A ufw-user-logging-forward -p udp -m udp -m conntrack -m limit -s 192.168.0.11/32 -d 192.168.0.47/32 -i wg-client8 -o wlp0s10f2 --dport 22 --sport 22 --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 --ctstate NEW -j LOG  --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
/etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save:-A ufw-user-logging-forward -p udp -m udp -s 192.168.0.11/32 -d 192.168.0.47/32 -i wg-client8 -o wlp0s10f2 --dport 22 --sport 22 -j RETURN
```

The above rules do not exist in ufw... and I can see that `192.168.0.11` is my external wi-fi device... which clearly shouldn't be need at all for a local rysnc job. :-/

any tips?

Comment: Your syntax doesn't look correct, nor do you even need to specify any IP addresses for local rsync. For local backup and from the destination directory, I do (dry-run test): `rsync --delete --archive --dry-run --verbose --exclude 'vm/*\.img' /home/doug ./`

Comment: rookie error... posting an answer now

Comment: @DougSmythies syntax correct.  I use rsync daemon for everything tom conserve resources

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  silly error.

I use the same command to pull backups from my vps, therefore, I of course, use the `--timeout=""` option.

In my situation, the timeout was getting triggered my while writing large files to an external hd drive (nowhere near as fast as my ssd drive).

Increasing the timeout to an hour `--timeout="3600"` got the above command work as intended.. (I also cleaned up my webmin iptables, no relation to this error)

Comment: +1, Thanks for sharing your solution.